# Doctrine MongoDB ODM embed document appending elements adding blank array

Tags: php, mongodb, doctrine-odm

```
return $this->persistantManager->createQueryBuilder( get_class( $user ) )
        ->field( 'field' )
        ->equals( 'data' )
        ->findAndUpdate()
        ->returnNew()
        ->field( 'info' )
        ->pushAll( $user->geInfo() )
```

`$user->geInfo()` returns `array` of info object. after executing it it adds a blank array everytime uner info field . `$user->geInfo()` returns populated data which it supposed to be inserted but it is not happening

**User object field annotation**

```
/** @ODM\EmbedMany(targetDocument="Info") */
    private $info = [];
```

**Info Object annotation**

```
 /** @ODM\ID */
        private $info;

        /** @ODM\Field(type="string") @ODM\Index */
        private $details;
```

Comment: So what is the question? You are telling us what is happening but I don't see you actually asking a question here. You don't want an empty array? This is pretty common in just about every ORM/ODM that you get such properties defined even if there are no values in the class instance you are persisting. So usually it's hard to turn off, if even possible.

Comment: `$user->geInfo()` returns populated data which it supposed to be inserted but it is not happneing @NeilLunn

Comment: @varuog you do have `->getQuery()->execute();` in the first snippet you posted, right?